# How to subtract a number(int) from a character in java

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

Hi I'm trying to subtract an int from a char but I keep being told that the compiler "cannot convert from int to char".
I have tried changing the constant to a char but it didn't help.

is there any easy way to do this subtraction?

test[1] = characterArray[1] - ASCII_SUB;

Any help much would be appreciated.

Comment: Cast `ASCII_SUB` to a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that subtraction is *never* performed on `char` values in Java. Instead, both operands are promoted to `int` (via [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)), and the result of the subtraction is an `int` as well. So you'll need to cast the result back to `char`:

```
test[1] = (char) (characterArray[1] - ASCII_SUB);
```

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers: What?